# Text is not correctly displaying in a TextView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm making a design in android using simple `LinearLayout` I create a `TextView` inside `CardView` when I enter long text inside `TextView` it hides some of the text, why this is happening? Check below image

[image: Image shows cutting text inside TextView]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/universal_padding"> <!-- 8dp -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCommentProfilePic"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/card_profile_pic_width_height"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/card_profile_pic_width_height"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/circular_photo" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCommentUserBadge"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/badge_width_height"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/badge_width_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/shap_circle_badge" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCommentUserFullName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                    android:text="Azeem Haider" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                    android:text=" - 2d"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCommentText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                android:text="This is a comment for testing purpose This is a comment for testing purpose This is a comment for testing purpose"
                 />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCommentProfilePic"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/kid" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCommentUserBadge"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_online" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCommentUserFullName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Azeem Haider"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" - 2d" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCommentText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a comment for testing purpose This is a comment for testing purpose This is a comment for testing purpose" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's working But can you please tell me the reason, So I don't make mistake further

Comment: Can you please let me know what the problem is why this is happening just removing `layout_weight="1"` and setting width as `wrap_content` in sperate view `LinearLayout of ImageView` how can it fix the `TextView` ???